# Python create objects in for loop

Tags: python

I have a class to assign some parameters:

```
class body:
    def __init__(self, name, number, L):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.L = L
```

And I would like to assign these parameters to 10 almost equal bodies like:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    body[i].name = "test_name"
    body[i].number = i
    body[i].L = 1.
```

And to be able to change, lets say, the parameter L of body 3 from 1 to 2:

```
body[3].L = 2
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that `body` is a class. Using `body[i]` suggests you may be intending to use `body` as a list. If you want to create a list of 10 *instances* of `body`, do not name the list `body` as well. You could instead name the list `bodies` and define it with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
bodies = [body("test_name", i, 1.) for i in range(0, 10)]
bodies[3].L = 2
```

---

By the way, [PEP8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends [all classes follow the CapWords convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). So to conform with the convention, `body` should be `Body`. By following this convention, everyone reading your code will understand immediately what is a class and what is not.